# What is the name of described pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

From high level perspective, the pattern makes possible to get polymorphic behavior without creating classes hierarchy.

It consists of 3 parts:

1. Data container classes, which have a certain field to be distinguished (e.g. User class with `country` field, or any class with `tenant` field in a multi-tenant saas project).
2. Context classes: these classes contain the data and logic which varies for different types of data containers (e.g. different logic for different tenants). There's a top-level Context class with all varying props set to default, and multiple derived classes which override defaults.
3. Data consumers/processors: these are business logic holders. They accept data container(s) and Context as parameters.

The 3rd-group citizen may have a method like:

```
Price getPrice(Price price, Context context) {
   double VAT = context.getVAT()
   return new Price(
           transform(price.amount + price.amount * VAT, price.currency, context.currency),
           context.currency
          )
}
...
//and here's the call:
Context ctx = getContext(principal.getCountry())
Price priceInUserCurrency = priceCalculator(priceInUsd, ctx);
```

Here's a simplified UML diagram:

[image]

Basic usage: when we need to introduce a different specific behavior for small groups of objects of the same class, 
we add a new method to `Context` with reasonable default value and implement the actual logic in concrete contexts. Then whereever we need to inject this piece of logic, we just call correspondent context method.

Comment: wouldn't a region based currency/price calculator be a strategy pattern?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are describing the [**Strategy Design Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

What gives it away is that you can perform `process()` for both PersonProcessor and PaymentProcessor. Like this example below.

[image]

Each object knows how to handle their own case of the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To me the description of

> makes possible to get polymorphic behavior without creating classes hierarchy

is more close to the concept of the [**State**](http://www.dofactory.com/net/state-design-pattern) design pattern.

[image]

Because it allow an object to alter its behavior when its internal state changes. The object will appear to change its class. Further more  also allows you to keep attributes of a former state even when the state changes afterwards.

About the inheritance part you [can read more here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225037/state-pattern-vs-inheritance).